# How to add payload (xml response & request logging) to CXF web service?

Tags: java, logging, mule, cxf

Colleagues, hello. I'm a little confused.
I have a simple dataflow made on Mule like this http://snag.gy/cJkzg.jpg
In fact it is a CXF SOAP web service.

Now i need to add response and request xml logging, but i don't know which way to select.
As i understood from internet there is next approaches:
1. Add Mule Logger element 
2. Under src/main/resources/META-INF/cxf/ (I have not this folder) create a file named org.apache.cxf.Logger with the following contents -

```
org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
```

and then add logger into my \src\main\resources\log4j.properties file.

It seems that's all I knew

At the current moment my log4j.properties looks like:

> log.dir=./logs datestamp=dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS
>   log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, defaultLog, errorlog
>
> ## all INFO logs log4j.appender.defaultLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>
> log4j.appender.defaultLog.Threshold=TRACE
>   log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
>   log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
>   log4j.appender.defaultLog.File=${log.dir}/serv.log
>   log4j.appender.defaultLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.defaultLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}}
>   %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n log4j.appender.defaultLog.encoding=UTF-8
>
> ## ERROR log log4j.appender.errorlog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>
> log4j.appender.errorlog.Threshold=ERROR
>   log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
>   log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
>   log4j.appender.errorlog.File=${log.dir}/serv.err
>   log4j.appender.errorlog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.errorlog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} %-5p
>   %c{1}:%L - %m%n
>
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>   log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=TRACE
>   log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} %-5p
>   %c{1}:%L - %m%n log4j.appender.stdout.encoding=UTF-8

As you see this properties file does not support payload logging.

How to add request & response logging in my case? I will be grateful for any code samples.
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I added interceptors into flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<flow name="Flow1" name="Flow1">
        <inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="45555" path="wserv" name="HTTP"/>
        <jaxws-service serviceClass="com.maya.ws.EndPoindImpl" name="CXF">

         <inInterceptors>
                    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
                </inInterceptors>
                <outInterceptors>
                    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </outInterceptors>

       </jaxws-service> 

        <component class="com.maya.ws.EndPoindImpl" name="Java"/>
    </flow>
```

And now i have xml payloads in console, but noy in log file.

**UPDATE 2**
Next lines added into log4j.properties

> log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=TRACE,
>   queryLog
>   log4j.additivity.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=true
>
> log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor=TRACE,
>   queryLog
>   log4j.additivity.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor=true
>
> ## Query log log4j.appender.queryLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
>
> log4j.appender.queryLog.File=${log.dir}/queryLog.log
>   log4j.appender.queryLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.queryLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x -
>   %m%n log4j.appender.queryLog.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
>   log4j.category.queryLogger=INFO, queryLog

queryLog is created but it is empty. =(

**UPDATE 3**

I add queryLog to the end of

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, defaultLog, errorlog
```

Now i have payloads in queryLog.log but the response looks as string. I'am trying to convert it in pretty xml.

Any idea how to convert into pretty xml response string in queryLog? :

```
Payload: <soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body> bla
bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a Logger in your flow in the Studio and set its message to #[payload], or add a  tag in the XML config mode. If the payload is a string, that will work directly, if it's a more complex object it will just print the object reference.

Generally you can add an Object to string transformer before you need to log your data. Sometimes you will have to be more creative with your transformations - check out what are available in Studio and don't be afraid to experiment.

Comment: I add logger element in flow with payload <logger message="#[payload]" level="TRACE" doc:name="Logger"/>. And nothing happens. Seems it is no easy.

Comment: You don't need to add payload in logger for CXF logging interceptor .. it will show the request and response in your console .. you just need to configure log4j correctly .. are you running in studio or standalone ?

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary, look: i add       <cxf:inInterceptors>
           <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
       </cxf:inInterceptors>
       <cxf:outInterceptors>
           <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
  and, you are absolutely right, payload is shown in console, not in log file. I develop in Anypoint studio, run app localy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exposing a CXF web service , you can always use **CXF interceptor** for **logging** your **Request and Response**.

Here this shows different CXF logging interceptor you can use for logging :-
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/CXF+Module+Configuration+Reference

And yes, in Mule standalone server, you may need log4j to display the logs in your console

Comment: I have log4j logging.

Comment: You can configure log4j.xml in **src/resource** folder by referring the following :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828634/mule-esb-are-the-log4j-config-for-batch-in-mule-need-separate-configuration    and can get the the request response display in console for standalone server .. for studio, I guess you can get it anyway.. but if you can't then add the log4j.xml file in your **src/resource** folder .. check the configuration of log4j.xml from the above link

Comment: I find an issue in your Mule config .. you are using **EndPoindImpl** in your  `<jaxws-service serviceClass="com.maya.ws.EndPoindImpl" name="CXF"> ` .. you should use the interface here instead of implementation class and your implementation class will be in your `<component class="com.maya.ws.EndPoindImpl" name="Java"/>` which is correct